# What type is identified with `{}` in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm using the type `{}` to identify an object in TypeScript but it pretty much seems to allow anything except `null` and `undefined`:

```
function foo(): {} {
  return "string";
}
```

The above example is valid TypeScript, so what type is declared in TypeScript when using `{}` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{}` will be compatible with any type (it has no required properties, index or call signatures).

If you want to return something that is not a primitive you can use `object`:

```
function foo(): object {
    return "string"; // error now 
}
```

The `object` type is documented [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html). Also, from the [PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1809) introducing the `object` type :

> The object type is the equivalent of `{}` minus the assignability of other basic type, that means that:
>
> 1. any other basic types are not assignable to object
> 2. any non-basic type is assignable to object
> 3. object is only assignable to `{}` and any

Comment: Thank you. Could you point me to the documentation that I seem to have missed.

Comment: @doberkofler added some doc references, hope it helps :)